# Can't stop event propagation between route controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-routing

I am using Angular Route to build an SPA with routes encapsulated by a common, parent controller. Inside the parent controller, there is a button that will emit an event that is suppose to be caught by all child/route controllers, each decide what to do with it.

And I would like for this event to be emitted once by the parent controller, and received once by each of the child/route controllers. I have a Plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/9twoe6WO3eLQzVDatrC0?p=preview that shows an unsuccessful attempt.

The issue with the snippet is that every time a route navigation occurs, the event is received one more time by the same child/route controller.

PS: code from Plunker

HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
    <button ng-click="navigate()">Propagate</button>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="viewIndexCtrl.html">
      <p>this is index page</p>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="viewPackageCtrl.html">
      <p>this is package page</p>
    </script>
  </body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/index', {
      controller: 'viewIndexCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'viewIndexCtrl.html'
    }).when('/package', {
      controller: 'viewPackageCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'viewPackageCtrl.html'
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/index'
    });
  }
]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
  $scope.navigate = function() {
    var route = location.href.indexOf('index') > -1 ? 'package' : 'index';

    $location.path('/' + route);
    $rootScope.$emit('navigate');
  };
});

app.controller('viewIndexCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('navigate', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    console.log('event reached index');
  });
});
app.controller('viewPackageCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('navigate', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    console.log('event reached package');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What you need is to use `$broadcast` rather than `$emit`.
- you put listeners on `$rootScope`, whenever a controller is destroyed it's scope is destroyed too thus all it's scope listeners are removed automatically, but when you put the listeners on `$rootScope` you need to manually remove them. what happens in your code is that you attach one listener to `$rootscope` with each route change without removing the previous listeners. If you'll use the controller's local `$scope` you don't have to do anything.

This is probably what you need ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jKUh3FrnWH53UVnhZn50?p=preview)):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  $scope.navigate = function() {
    var route = location.href.indexOf('index') > -1 ? 'package' : 'index';
    $location.path('/' + route);
    // $location.path happens only after the digest cycle so we must wait for it..
    $timeout(function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('navigate');  
    });
  };
});

app.controller('viewIndexCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.$on('navigate', function(e) {
    console.log('event reached index');
  });
});
app.controller('viewPackageCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.$on('navigate', function(e) {
    console.log('event reached package');
  });
});
```